# I have installed C++ compiler mingw-w64 file using Ubuntu terminal, but now I am not able to locate its path to VS Code(code editor), so what to do?

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, compiler

Installed mingw files :
g++-mingw-w64
gcc-mingw-w64

I tried on community, but no one had posted this Question

Comment: I think you want g++-mingw-w64-x86-64 and gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64
Assuming that you want to build for amd64 architecture.

Answer (score 0):

They are located inside dir `/usr/bin/x86_64-*`